# Image based on node taxonomy terms

Tags: 7, theming, taxonomy-terms

Here is what I am trying to do.

If there is an empty image field on a node I want it replaced based on what taxonomy terms are on the page, but the key is I want to apply it site wide so it will affect not only the tpl files but Views as well. I'm guessing this needs to be done via mytheme_preprocess_field in template.php but I'm not quite sure how to do it.

I can easily do this in node.tpl.php but I need it done site wide, not just in the node-type template.

- VID 1

  - TID 1
  - TID 2
  - TID 3
  - TID 4
- VID 2

  - TID 5
  - TID 6
  - TID 7
- VID 3

  - TID 8
  - TID 9
  - TID 10

Here is what I am trying to do.

```php
// Set Variables
$term1 = $content['field_term1'][0]['#markup'];
// Must use if statement or else there will be an error
if ( isset( $content['field_term2'][0]['#markup'] ) ) {
  $term2 = $content['field_term2'][0]['#markup'];
}
// Must use if statement or else there will be an error
if ( isset( $content['field_term3'][0]['#markup'] ) ) {
  $travel_type = $content['field_term3'][0]['#markup'];
}
if (isset($content['field_node_image'][0]['#item']['uri'])) {
  $image_path = file_create_url($content['field_node_image'][0]['#item']['uri']);
} else {
  switch ($term1) {
    case 'TID 1':
      switch ($term2) {
        case 'TID 5':
          $term_type = '5';
          break;
        case 'TID 6':
          $term_type = '6';
          break;
        case 'TID 7':
          $term_type = '7';
          break;
      }
      break;
    case 'TID 2':
      $term_type = '2';
      break;
    case 'TID 3':
      switch ($term3) {
        case 'TID 8':
          $term_type = '8';
          break;
        case 'TID 9':
          $term_type = '9';
          break;
        case 'TID 10':
          $term_type = '10';
          break;
      }
      break;
    case 'TID 4':
      $term_type = '4';
      break;
  }
  $image_path = '/sites/all/themes/themename/term-images/' . $term_type . '.jpg';
}
```

Comment: all you need to do is described here: [Achieve Taxonomy Image function in Drupal 7 with Imagefield](https://drupal.org/node/1224916).

Comment: I've updated my question to make a bit more sense of what exactly I am trying to do.

Comment: If user will choose any term from your vocabulary, then his post will contain some image related with this term, right?

Answer (score 0):

I used to use the [Taxonomy Image](https://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_image) module. It has full views integration as well.

```
Features:

    Image configuration happens within existing admin/taxonomy menu structure.
    Admins can add custom tags to <img> markup when displaying images.
    Allows one-to-one term-to-image relationships.
    Allows many-to-one term-to-image relationships.
    Admin-permitted users can disable the images.
    Administrators can force images to be a standard size.
    May use the ImageCache module if it is available.
    Works with Views.
    Utilizes core file.inc and taxonomy.module APIs.
    Small module with specific, focused functionality.
    Add-on modules that virtually eliminate the need for theme changes.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do some custom coding based on what's in the node from the field template you can get to the node from $variables in preprocess_field like so:

```
// Parent entity could be a node or custom fieldable entity, usually going to be a node.
if(!empty($variables['element']['#object'])){
  $parent_entity = &$variables['element']['#object'];
}
```

At this point you can do whatever you were doing in the node preprocess in the field preprocessor. This can potentially get a bit heavy, so beware